# Display Updated Data after a ButtonClick

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, refresh

I am new to this technology and I am facing a small issue. I am updating date to database and displaying a Message like "Published Successfully" on a button click but I want the date to be updated as well.
I tried adding Refresh code, but then the Message is not displayed as it triggers immediately the refresh.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="PublishManifestCtrl">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-header bordered-bottom bordered-themeprimary">
            <i class="widget-icon fa fa-tasks themeprimary"></i>
            <span class="widget-caption themeprimary">Manifest Status</span>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body">
            <form class="form-bordered" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="padding-left: 8px;">Manifest was last published to agents on <b>{{manifeststatus.manifestLastPublishedDate}}</b>.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="padding-left: 8px;">Manifest was last updated by <b> {{manifeststatus.lastUpdatedByUser}} </b> on <b>{{manifeststatus.manifestLastedUpdatedDate}}</b>.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
                        <button id="PublishButton" class="btn btn-default shiny " ng-disabled="manifeststatus.enablePublishButton" ng-click="Save()">Publish</button>
                    </div>    
                </div>

                <div id="statusDivPublish"  ng-show="showstatus" >
                        <alert  type="{{alert.type}}">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
app.controller('PublishManifestCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope,          $http,$state,$stateParams) {
$scope.showstatus = false;

$http({
    url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus',
    params: { 'foobar': new Date().getTime() }
}).
success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric", hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric" };

    data.manifestLastedUpdatedDate = (new Date(data.lastUpdatedDateTime)).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    data.manifestLastPublishedDate = (new Date(data.lastPublishDateTime)).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    var date1 = new Date(data.lastUpdatedDateTime);
    var date2 = new Date(data.lastPublishDateTime);
    data.enablePublishButton = date2.getTime() > date1.getTime();

    $scope.manifeststatus = data;

}).
error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('error' + status);
    // log error
});
$scope.Save = function () {
    $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');

    //refresh
    $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
        reload: true,
        inherit: false,
        notify: true
   });

    //to show Publish message
    $scope.showstatus = true;
    $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
    $(".statusDivPublish").show();

      }});
```

[image: Before Clicking Publish Button]

[image: After Clicking The Button]

[image: The date get refreshed after Refreshing the page]

Comment: what is the `<alert>`? Is it a directive you created? If thats a directive you can modfiy that directive and have return value from the alert. Once you receive the return value you fire the `$http.get` again.

Comment: That `$http({...})` does not have method type, add `method:'GET'` inside

Comment: @AbhishekPandey im talking about this: `$http({
    url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus',
    params: { 'foobar': new Date().getTime() }
})`, add `method:'GET'` inside

Comment: As you are using `$state.transitionTo` why dont you register with the event `$stateChangeSuccess` to show the alert?

Comment: @Nilesh : I have used in this way 
 //refresh
 $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true});
        

        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            $scope.showstatus = true;
            $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
            $(".statusDivPublish").show();
        });

But the page get refreshed but the alert is not shown.